# How to create a subdomain which points to mobile site

Tags: iis, dns, subdomain

I got a domain in GoDaddy which points to my server (A record).

Recently, i developed a mobile site (my desktop site is allready in production and runs on IIS 8.5 lets call it www.domain.com).

I wanted to create a subdomain which points to my mobile site - m.domain.com.
I created a subdirectory in my desktop site - m folder which contains the mobile site.
I created a CNAME record in GoDaddy m that points to m.domain.com.
But when i'm trying to connect to m.domain.com i get - DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

Glad if you can tell me what do you think caused the problem, or if you got an other idea how to configure m.domain.com.

Thank you.

Comment: m `CNAME` record should not point to itself, you probably want `m CNAME www.domain.com.`

Comment: OK, but then when the user will browse m.domain.com he will see the desktop version isn't he?

Comment: yes, the purpose of DNS is just to direct the user to correct ip address. The rest you have to configure in IIS (it has been many years since I have done it in IIS, but is should be fairly simple: you configure the new website, with `m.domain.com` as Host name, and appropriate root folder, so IIS will know what content to show based on hostname that user typed in browser address bar )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Dusan you don't have to do anything in GoDaddy since your domain already redirects to your server IP. Follow below steps and you should be good to go -

1. Go To IIS Manager
2. Right Click on Sites -> Add WebSite . Configure as below i.e. Physical Path pointing to sub directory and host name to m.domain.com

[image]

Make sure to remove CName in GoDaddy. Hope this helps.